# Sur « se faire + verbe à l'infinitif » dans le contexte

Tags: expressions

> Cependant, sous la pluie des pensums, l'ordre peu à peu se rétablit dans la classe, et le professeur, parvenu à saisir le nom de Charles Bovary, **se l'étant fait dicter, épeler et relire**, commanda tout de suite au pauvre diable d'aller s'asseoir sur le banc de paresse, au pied de la chaire.

(*Madame Bovary*, [Chapitre I](https://books.google.ro/books?id=RlYbAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT367&lpg=PT367&dq=%22se%20l%27%C3%A9tant%20fait%20dicter,%20%C3%A9peler%22&source=bl&ots=8ZFIbMjdcb&sig=yOcdE33RFuy2ib2Ft3WRPG9mdk4&hl=ro&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq69yWgdTUAhVHrxoKHadbDB0Q6AEINjAC#v=onepage&q=%22se%20l%27%C3%A9tant%20fait%20dicter%2C%20%C3%A9peler%22&f=false))

Sans le pronom élidé *le*, si j'ai bien compris cette forme verbale, *s'étant fait* est au participe passé, et peut être traduite en anglais comme : *having done*.

Mais dans le contexte du texte déjà cité, la structure *se faire + verbe à l'infinitif*, qui peut être traduite en anglais comme *get + verb in the infinitive*, je crois que *se l'étant fait dicter, épeler et relire* peut être traduit comme ça : *getting it [the name] dictated, spelled and reread*. (Mais *getting it [the name] dictated, spelled and reread* ne semble pas bien en anglais).

Ai-je bien compris la structure grammaticale de *se l'étant fait dicter, épeler et relire* ? Comment pourrais-je la reformuler ou la traduire en anglais afin de la comprendre mieux ?

Comment: Telle qu'elle est formulée cette question n'est pas à sa place, on peut demander une demande d'explication sur la structure *se faire + verbe à l'infinitif* mais pas de traduction dans une autre langue :[Don't ask about...How to translate a French expression into another language](https://french.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a translation into another language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ça pourrait être intéressant d'essayer de trouver une version publiée en anglais pour voir comment le traducteur s'est débrouillé avec ce passage. (Mieux encore, des versions, traduites par des personnes différentes.)

Il me semble que le problème épineux avec cette expression est la forme pronominale, qui est difficile à rendre en anglais sans que la tournure ne paraisse boiteuse. Le "*having done*" proposé pour traduire "*s'étant fait*" traduirait plutôt "*ayant fait*", sans l'élément pronominal que contient la tournure française.

Je n'ai pas de traduction idéale, mais je pencherais vers quelque chose qui ne reprend pas exactement la tournure française.

> having managed to identify Charles Bovary after his name had been uttered, spelt out, and confirmed, the teacher...

Je n'en suis pas entièrement satisfait, mais pour faire mieux il faudrait que je traduise la scène au complet et que je relise et révise cette traduction quelque jour plus tard, en ne regardant que l'anglais.

Comment: Nice answer. C'est ce à quoi je pensais moi aussi : l'élément pronominal manque aux autres traductions. I would say that *se* as an indirect reflexive object here means: "to himself (i.e. the teacher), for himself, for his own benefit". Hence I would have rendered it: `...the teacher, who had got his head around the name 'Charles Bovary' after having had it dictated to him, spelt out, and read aloud again, at once commanded the poor devil...`

Comment: Consulting [this translation](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2413/2413-h/2413-h.htm#link2HCH0001) by Eleanor Marx-Aveling, I see the pronoun was handled similarly: `...the master having succeeded in catching the name of “Charles Bovary,” having had it dictated to him, spelt out, and re-read, at once ordered the poor devil...`

Comment: @LukeSawczak I like "got his head around" for "saisir! You're spot on about the meaning of "*se*" as the indirect object as well. Also, I'm a little surprised at how literal the translation you found turned out to be.

Answer (score 2):

Comme `se l'étant fait` est un passif, je le traduirais par

> he had it dictated, spelled and proofread/reviewed

Answer (score 0):

La tournure française est un peu lourde si on la transcrit directement en anglais. Je propose:

> the professor managed to capture the name of Charles Bovary, to have it
>   dictated, spelled and verified, and ordered the poor devil to sit...

Certes, on perd la relation temporelle entre les deux propositions, mais on garde le rythme et la respiration de la phrase, importants pour l'effet littéraire, sans la rendre trop lourde. Une alternative est "having had it dictated, spelled and verified", pour garder la concordance des temps, mais je trouve ça plus lourd. Je préfère garder un rythme similaire au français

Comment: En anglais, "*to have it...*", ça donnerait plutôt "pour le faire dicter, épeler et relire". Tu ne pensais pas à "*having had it* dictated, spelled and verified", par hasard?

Comment: @Philippe J'essaye d'éviter passif + gerondif, un peu lourd en anglais, surtout au passé. Si je mets "the professor managed to capture", je ne peux pas utiliser votre tournure. Comme ça, je garde le sens inchangé.

Comment: Pour la phrase qui nous intéresse ici, je pense qu'une certaine lourdeur est inévitable. J'ai beaux me creuser les méninges, je ne trouve pas de construction anglaise qui soit à la fois légère et capable d'exprimer correctement la relation temporelle entre le "*parvenu à saisir*" et le "*se l'étant fait*".

Comment: C'est vrai qu'il y a un léger "contresens" dans ma traduction, car je ne rends pas compte du fait que la dictée entraîne la compréhension du nom, mais celà ne me dérange pas. Je pense qu'on peut même dire tout simplement "The professor managed to have the name of C. B. dictated, spelled and verified".

Comment: Ou alors "The professor managed to understand C. B.'s name after it was dictated, and spelled to it." On oublie "vérifié" parce que ça ne peut pas marcher dans cette tournure, et on perd le beau rythme ternaire qui donne son sens à la phrase. La traduction est quelques fois affaire de compromis :)

Comment: Je me pose une question en lisant vos deux premières traductions: qui, selon vous, "*dicte, épelle, et relit" le nom de Charles Bovary dans la phrase originale? Dans votre dernière traduction, est-ce le "to it" à la fin serait un faute de frappe?

Comment: "to him", bien évidemment... Le sens est : le professeur a enfin compris le nom de C. B. après qu'on (on ne sait pas qui, mais probablement Charles) lui aie dicté, epelé, et qu'on (le même on) l'aie relu.