# Sur le sens de l'expression « en traduction vouvoyante »

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

Je crois que l'adjectif **vouvoyante** dans cette expression est venu du participe présent, **vouvoyant**, du verbe **vouvoyer**.

Mais je ne sais pas ce que veut dire vraiment ce mot dans cette expression, que j'ai vue dans ce contexte :

> Pour justifier le subjonctif présent habeas (« que vous ayez », **[en
>   traduction vouvoyante](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habeas_corpus)**), on peut considérer oportet (« il faut »)
>   comme sous-entendu : oportet corpus habeas (« il faut que vous ayez le
>   corps »).

Je n'ai trouvé le mot **vouvoyante** en adjectif nulle part.

Comment: Cette question, comme [la précédente](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26259/sur-se-faire-verbe-%C3%A0-linfinitif-dans-le-contexte) est hors sujet sur FSE. [*Don't ask about... How to translate a French expression into another language*](https://french.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: @jlliagre Where am I supposed to find out the answer to this question if not here? If no dictionary has this expression translated, how am I supposed to learn what it means? Before you close it down, you might as well tell me what it means.If this is still _a learning site_, offer some help before you close questions down.

Comment: You should then rephrase your question to ask about the meaning of this adjective in this context.

Comment: @jlliagre Have you at least read my question with proper attention? I did what you just said I should've done: Mais je ne sais pas comment traduire en anglais _ce mot_ dans cette expression [...] And if my text is not up to the standards of your rules, you should have edited yourself instead of making such haste to close it down.

Comment: @jlliagre is just trying to help you write your question to fit the standards of the site (they're not "their" standards). Once you have edited it anyone having submitted a close vot can retract it.

Comment: THIS "RULE" ACCORDING TO WHICH YOU CANNOT ASK FOR TRANSLATIONS OF _SPECIFIC_ WORDS AND EXPRESSIONS IS ABSURD, AND NO LAWS OR RULES ARE IMMUTABLE. ALL RULES CAN BE CHANGED IF PROVEN ABSURD.

Comment: There are other places to ask for translations into another language. [French Language is a question and answer site ... to discuss the finer points of the French language](https://french.stackexchange.com/tour). Il suffisait de demander ce que veut dire « en traduction vouvoyante », et je pense que tous les francophones ne comprendraient pas.

Comment: Asking for an English word should be done in a English related site. You should just have rephrased your question for it to fit the site rules. If you disagree, the right location to state your point is here: [meta](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/) .

Comment: This is a way you could rephrase your question: « Je pense que l'adjectif *vouvoyante* dans cette expression vient du participe présent *vouvoyant*, du verbe vouvoyer.
Mais je ne suis pas sûr de bien comprendre cette expression que j'ai vue dans ce contexte :.... ». I answered [there](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38340416#38340416)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Tutoyant* et *vouvoyant* ne sont pratiquement pas utilisés comme adjectifs en français. J'ai eu beaucoup de mal à trouver un exemple, en voici un, en dehors de celui donné dans la question, qui vient  sur le forum [ABC de la langue française](http://www.languefrancaise.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=11413) au sujet d'une traduction du latin vers le français :

> Notez que quand on dit en latin *mecum* (avec moi), *tecum* (avec toi, ou “avec vous” en traduction vouvoyante), il s'agit d'un verlan institutionnalisé car on attendait plutôt “cum me” ou “cum te”.

En général on dit « si /quand on emploie le tutoiement  », « si / quand on emploie le vouvoiement ».

Dire « en traduction vouvoyante » ne me semble pas très joli et fait très jargonnant, même si ça ne fait pas partie du jargon de spécialiste (employé par les traducteurs).

> « Comment traduirais-tu *Can you swim* en français ? 
>   - *Est-ce que tu sais nager*  si je tutoie la personne (« en traduction tutoyante »), *est-ce que vous savez nager* si je vouvoie la personne (« en traduction vouvoyante ») ».

Comment: Effectivement, ça prend un peu par surprise comme usage, même si ça se comprend. Peut-être que c'est un jargon limité à des latinistes qui cherchaient un formule plus courte que « employer le vouvoiement ».

Answer (score 2):

Dans l'exemple cité le latin *habeas* se réfère à la deuxième personne du singulier ("tu" en français, l'interlocuteur à qui on parle). Une traduction plausible en français serait donc "que tu aies".

Cependant en français on n'utilise pour désigner son interlocuteur la deuxième personne du pluriel ("vous") quand on veut marquer le respect ou la distance, il est donc possible de traduire "habeas" par "que vous ayez".

Si on opte pour la première traduction il s'agit d'une traduction "tutoyante" (qui utilise le tutoiement), si on opte pour la seconde il s'agit d'une traduction "vouvouyante" (qui utilise le vouvoiement).

Je n'ai jamais vu cet adjectif utilisé autrement que dans ce contexte précis. Par exemple on ne dit pas de quelqu'un qu'il est "vouvoyant" si il a l'habitude de vouvoyer les gens.